# How to escalate privilege through base64 binary when it is SUID

Tags: linux, bash, base64, sh, suid

i was trying a CTF, where i found base64 binary as SUID. I checked through linpeas too where it said its vulnerable .I tried to escalate privilege by using following steps:

1.Made a file named exploit and put following code in it.
'''
chmod +s /bin/sh
'''

2.Now i encoded it in base64
'''
cat exploit|base64
'''
resulting to Y2htb2QgK3MgL2Jpbi9zaAo=

3.Then i used the following code to get it executed.

'''base64 -d <<< Y2htb2QgK3MgL2Jpbi9zaAo= |sh''' and it says operation not permitted

i tried changing the exploit script to
'''/bin/bash -p'''
and
'''
#!/bin/sh
/bin/bash -p
'''

but it just gives me a normal bash shell.
can anyone explain why is the base64 being a SUID and vulnerable not giving a root shell and how to get root shell?
(Sorry if i did something terribly wrong...m just a learner :)

Comment: From the bash manual: "_Each  command  in a pipeline is executed as a separate process_". So your `sh` is executed with your own privileges, no more.

Comment: You probably need to understand what this `base64` utility does (e.g., what libraries it uses if it's binary, what commands it calls if it's a script...) and see if you can substitute something it uses by your own thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an exploit at all. You just try to execute chmod command, and there is no difference if you are trying to execute it from shell, or encode/decode to base64 and then execute it from shell.

I suppose, the initial idea was to encode chmod command and give obfuscated command to very-very stupid user. who has superuser privileges , so he will execute it with superuser privileges and anybody, who run "sh" will run sh with superuser privileges.

Summary: encoding to base64 is not a vulnerability or exploit. It is just encoding something to string.
The way how you will find the possibility to run this with superuser privileges should be an exploit.

Comment: Thank you, i tried to put a reverse shell code in exploit file, i got the connection back but it doesn't give a root shell. My question is if base64 is SUID file and it gives back a reverse shell, isn't it suppose to maintain the privilege without dropping it? (Any suggestions to gain the root access will be helpful)

Comment: Did you got an idea, that SUID is attribute of file on disk, not attribute of base64 string?
It is a not exploit file, it is just a chmod command, which requires superuser privileges. It is not becomes an exploit if you just encode this command with base64.